# reject promise when returning $http from service

Tags: angularjs

I know I could do this:

```
angular.module('app.services').service('Resources', function ($q) {
  this.ProductData = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get(url)
        .then(function(result) {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }, function() {
            defered.reject("error");
        });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
```

But could I avoid creating deferred obj, but still be able to do both resolve and reject?

```
angular.module('app.services').service('Resources', function () {
  this.ProductData = function() {

    return $http.get(url)
        .then(function (result) {
            // how would I do 'deferred.resolve or deferred.reject' here?
        }, function () {
            // how would I do 'deferred.reject' here?
        });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to avoid creating a `deferred` and another promise for `$http`.

If you need to reject the promise while the actual `$http` call has succeeded, you'd need to return `$q.reject()`:

```
return $http.get(url)
    .then(function(result){
       if (result.data.length === 0) return $q.reject("error");

       return result;
    }
```

Comment: oh! so $q is the same as deferred would be?
should I use `$q.resolve(data)` or `return data` when resolving?

Comment: there's no `$q.resolve`, so just return the value or another promise